# Increasing array size

Tags: java, arrays, copy

I just started learning java and I'm having a problem in increasing an array's size with a new length provided by the user.

If the user's input is greater than 10 (the initial array's size), then I want to increase the array's size according to the user's input.

This is done within the `checkFull(int, int)` method, however after copying the `newArray` in `articles` the size is still 10.

Am I doing it completely wrong?

```
int[][] articles = new int[10][3];

public static int[][] checkFull(int[][] articles, int noOfArticles) {
    System.out.print("Ange antal nya artiklar: ");
    int noOfNewArticles = input();
    if (noOfNewArticles > 10) {
        int[][] newArray = Arrays.copyOf(articles, articles.length + (noOfNewArticles - articles.length));
        articles = Arrays.copyOf(newArray, newArray.length);
    }
    return articles;
}
```

Comment: I see one problem already I think.  If the current array size is 10 and you add one more article to the array, what does `articles.length+(noOfNewArticles-articles.length)` work out to be?

Comment: if the user enter 11 for example
articles.length+(noOfNewArticles-articles.length) this translates to:
     10             +(        11           -             10)

so the new array will be 11

Comment: Why the double `Arrays.copyOf`?

Comment: OK, so why subtract?  If the user passes in 11, and you want 11 as a result, why add and then subtract `articles.length`?  (Look at the problem as algebra, how do you simplify `x + (y-x)`?)

Comment: Welcome to Java!  As an alternative approach to managing the array capacity yourself, you could check out the Collections API - in particular the ArrayList implemenation of the List interface - it auto scales a backing array for you, you can simply just add articles whenever you need to.  It's not without overhead but way more convenient when you're dealing with an unknown number of things.  Theres' a LinkedList implemation too if that's better for you.

Answer (score 0):

`articles.length + (noOfNewArticles - articles.length)` is just `noOfNewArticles`. You also never use `noOfArticles`, so I changed it to `noOfNewArticles`.

I tried simplifying your code, and it worked fine for me:

```
public static int[][] checkFull(int[][] articles, int noOfNewArticles) {
    if (noOfNewArticles > 10) {
        return Arrays.copyOf(articles, noOfNewArticles);
    }
    return articles;
}
```

When I run

```
int[][] articles = new int[10][3];
for (int i = 0; i<20;i++){
    System.out.println((checkFull(articles, i)).length);
}
```

I get

```
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
```

Comment: Thank you Jhanzaib, i think it worked. Got another error but i think it is reated to another loop.